# Complex HABTM query that I can't do

Tags: cakephp

Using CakePhp 2.3
Hi everyone, I'm trying to make a complex query on my system but I can't figure how to get it done. So here is the thing :
It's an event system, members can create events and register to them. For this I have 3 tables: users, events and events_users. users HABTM events, events HABTM users.
I have 3 models as well:
**User.php**

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel{

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Event');
    public $hasMany = array('EventUser');
}
```

**Event.php**

```
<?php
class Event extends AppModel{

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('User');
    public $hasMany = array('EventUser');

}
```

**EventUser.php**

```
<?php
class EventUser extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'events_users';
    public $belongsTo = array('Event', 'User');

}
```

In my UsersController, I have an action called "show($id)" which purpose is to display the events a user has created and registered. Here is the controller:
**UsersController.php**

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController{
function show($id){

        // User info
        $user = $this->User->find('first', array(
            'recursive' => 0,
            'conditions' => array('User.id' => $id)
            ));

        // Registered events
        $registered = $this->User->EventUser->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('User.id' => $id)
            ));

        // Created Events
        $created = $this->User->Event->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('Event.userid' => $id)
            ));
        $this->set(compact('user', 'registered', 'created'));

    }
}
```

Check the second query I called "Registered events". What I wanna do in here is to get all the events this user has subscribed to and also all the other users who have subscribed to the same events than him. It would be an array like:

```
    <?php
    (int) 0 => array(
            'Event' => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'name' => 'event 1',
            ),
            'EventUser' => array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                    'id' => '2',
                    'user_id' => '32',
                    'event_id' => '2'
                ),
                (int) 1 => array(
                    'id' => '4',
                    'user_id' => '29',
                    'event_id' => '2'
                ),
                (int) 2 => array(
                    'id' => '6',
                    'user_id' => '38',
                    'event_id' => '2'
                )
            ),
            'User' => array(
                    'id' => '38',
                    'username' => 'username 1',
                )
            )
        ),
...
?>
```

In the example above, you can see that the user id=38 has registered to the event id=2 but also that there are others registered with him: 'user_id' => '32' and 'user_id' => '29'.

That's pretty much about it. Does anybody has an idea to build this query?
Thanks a lot in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You only need one model User
code should be

```
 <?php
    class User extends AppModel{

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Event');

    }
```

now in your action just write following

```
$data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however with this query I get all the elements where the id of the user is present. What I would like is to get all the events where there is this user and the other ones. In fact the query would say something like that: fetch all the events where user_id = 1 in events_users and in all the events he registered fetch the other users registered with him. I guess it would has to be queried in the events_users, I guess no? I'm so lost ^^

Comment: along with this use Containable http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Comment: Thanks for your help but I just gave up it's getting too much complicated for what I needed so I keep it simple.